# How to define CHAR datatype in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to link my nodejs sequelize backend to an already existing database. But I cannot find how to define char datatype in sequelize. Which is very weird since all the other datatypes are available and well documented.

https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html

The only other link I found for char was : [https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/data-types.js~CHAR.html](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/data-types.js%7ECHAR.html) but I can't seem to figure out what it actually means and how to practically implement it.

The only char data fields that I was successfully able to define using sequelize were the uuid fields which translate to char(36) in mysql through sequelize.

Answer (score 1):

On your migration file use: `type: Sequelize.CHAR`

To specific size use: `type: Sequelize.CHAR(20)` --> 20 characters.

Example:

```
firstName: {
   type: Sequelize.CHAR(10)
}
```

NOTE: Remember to refresh the database client after run:

```
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use String like in one of my models class

name: { type: DataTypes.STRING(128), allowNull: true},

Comment: DataTypes.STRING will create a VARCHAR column. Op requested a CHAR column.